# Rename images to the folder name with Python

Tags: python, file-rename

I want to rename images that were previously copied from multiple subfolders to the name of the subfolder from which the image came. With my actual code I can only rename images, when I enter the actual file name. But this name always varies.

For example:

```
C:/sub/folder/1/
```

rename these images from this folder to 1.jpg

My actual code:

```
paths = (os.path.join(root, filename)
for root, _, filenames in os.walk(dir_dst):
    for filename in filenames:        
        for path in paths:
            newname= path.replace('image_name','new_image_name')
            if newname != path:
                os.rename(path, newname)
```

I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: What is exactly the error or the unexpected behavior you get?

Comment: The current code works, but I can only say rename image "abc.jpg" to "xyz.jpg". But I want to rename different image names to the name of the folder they were copied from.

Comment: Do u have multiple images in the same folder or only one?

Comment: It's not always the same. Sometimes only one picture, sometimes four pictures.

Comment: So if you have two images in the same subfolder, both of them should be named 1.jpg? Names should be unique...

Comment: That's right. I would have thought of something like that: 1_1.jpg, 1_2.jpg or something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
import os, shutil

src_g = os.getcwd()
dst_g0 = src_g.split('\\')
dst_g0.pop()
dst_g = '\\'.join(dst_g0)+'\\DestinationFolder\\'

for i in os.listdir(src_g):
    if os.path.isdir(i):
        name = i
        neuer_pfad = src_g+'\\'+name+'\\folder_with_images\\'
        for j in os.listdir(neuer_pfad):
            neue_datei = neuer_pfad+j
            if os.path.isfile(neue_datei):
                shutil.copyfile(neue_datei, dst_g+name+'_'+j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this

```
x = os.path.abspath('file_to_rename')
x = os.path.dirname(x)
x = os.path.basename(x)
```

That will set the name of the current folder to `x`. From there you could design some incrementing loop with `i` and rename your files to

```
os.rename('file_to_rename', x + '_' + str(i))
```

and then just increase `i += 1`